# Get duplicates from array of objects by value

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects:

```
var arr = [
  {number: "AL-32021611", b: "7500"}, 
  {number: "AL-32021612", b: "Continental"}, 
  {number: "AL-32021612", b: "R3"}, 
  {number: "AL-32021612", b: "7500"}
];
```

Is there a way that I can get all the number coincidences and get insted of number values the 'b' values in a var?

for example

```
//loop

result = ["Continental", "R3", "7500"]
```

what i want is for example i recive the number and then i search all the coincidences with that number value and what i exactly need is all the values from the coincidences

Comment: So you want to discard the entries where there's a single occurrence of a particular value for `number`? Shouldn't the result be something like `{"AL-32021612": ["Continental", "R3", "7500"]}? What should the result be if the first element of `arr` is `{number: "AL-32021611" , b: "United"}` instead?

Comment: what i want is for example  i recive the number and then i search all the coincidences with that number value and what i exactly need is all the values from the coincidences

Answer (score 2):

Using ES6 features:

```
let result = Array.from(new Set(arr.map(el => el.b)));
```

or

```
let result = [...new Set(arr.map(el => el.b))];
```

- [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)
- [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)
- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- [Spread Operator `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

Comment: I don't think this is what OP wants. From the comments, it sounds like OP wants to supply a particular `number` value and obtain a list of corresponding `b` values.

Answer (score 0):

Str has a nice one-line answer for you, but you can also do it explicitly with a simple for loop. See below.

As you have it,

```
result = {"Continental", "R3" , "7500"};
```

is not a valid object. You could use a for loop and push the b values into a new array that would look like:

result = ["Continental", "R3" , "7500"];

Your for loop would look like:

```
var result = [];
for(var n of arr) {
    result.push(arr[n].b);
}
return result;
```